How many uncoordinated cubers does it take to solve a Rubik's cube with multiple solutions?
Inspired by Rubik's cubes with multiple sets of colors or stickers. Suppose there's a Rubik's cube with multiple solutions (represented by multiple sets of colors) made with special paint that reflect specific wavelengths and polarization of light, such that one can only see one set of colors at a time using a special type of filtering glasses, and nobody can see multiple sets of colors at the same time. A group of cubers are allowed to enter the room one by one, each person must borrow a random pair of the special glasses, so they can see a random set of colors only(each set equally likely to be seen), and each person must turn the cube once and then return the glasses and leave the room. They can discuss before the first person enters the room, but cannot communicate in any way afterwards. How many cubers does it take on average to reach a solved state in any set of colors, and what's their best strategy?
You can assume all sets of colors are solvable, and when one set is solved, all other sets are scrambled. The cube starts scrambled in all sets of colors, and you can assume the number of sets is known. Turning the cube 180 degrees is allowed. Specific answers are fine if no general answer is found. There can be as many cubers as needed, but they can't repeat visits.

Is a no-op allowed? ie. Enter the room, put on glasses, observe the cube without touching, return glasses, leave

@ApexPolenta I don't think so, they are supposed to turn the cube :) But I'm curious how no-op can help significantly, it seems to me it shouldn't help that much if at all.

I'd be very surprised if there were any non-bruteforce solution to this.

@alices_and_bobs It helps because I had an idea of a possible strategy. You'd need a group of cubers who know CFOP and have practiced identifying mid-algorithm states of the cube. Then, the strategy would be to concentrate on one particular set of colors, and just no-op for any others. Without the option to no-op, this strategy can't get off the ground, and in fact I'm not sure if any strategy could. In which case the fallback would be to rely on the Hamiltonian circuit, requiring quintillions of moves.

@ApexPolenta Feel free to add an answer if you think no-op is necessary for a realistic solution. Though I wonder: is it always  possible to identify mid-algorithm states? Does that mean cubers can easily solve an ordinary cube by turning once each without communicating? That sounds surprising but I'm not familiar with CFOP. Also, how do the cubers in question know which set of colors they are looking at and agree on one set to turn? The sets are not numbered.

@alices_and_bobs Do you know if there is a solution to this that does not visit (almost) every state of the cube?

@TimSeifert I think there are. I haven't proved rigorously.

I don’t understand the problem at all. Is it a 3x3x3 cube? What does « multiple solutions mean? Does it mean that some pair of glasses allow to see, for example,only red and orange tiles? Are the glasses recognizable (if I enter the room again, can I choose the glasses I put on the time before?)?

@Plop I intended a 3x3x3 cube, but if you have a solution for a different size, feel free to add an answer. Multiple solutions: I mean like these https://youtu.be/bnEgplsPedw or https://youtu.be/fL7HS2DXT6k but if the only clue is colors so you can only see one set of colors (that determine a solution) at a time and each set looks just like a normal cube through the glasses so you don't see other distracting clues such as angle or shape. They can't choose or directly compare multiple pairs of glasses. If they want to leave clues, any information left for others must be through the cube.

@Plop I mean if your solution somehow requires assuming glasses are recognizable (even though they aren't allowed to return to the room or to pick glasses, if they were allowed to do so they would have been able to pick out the glasses they used), feel free to post your solution. But remember that they can't communicate after the game starts, and can't tell others anything about the glasses or colors they saw except through turning the cube.

Ok I had missed some points. But the videos are not enough for me to understand the rules of the puzzle.

How many solvers are there? If there's a finite number of them, then I have a simple solution.
